# For and against vs pros and cons

Tags: meaning

As far as I understand, these phrases have very similar meaning, but is there any difference between them at all? I mean, are they interchangeable?

> We discussed pros and cons of buying a bigger house.

Would it be correct to say?

> We discussed for and against of buying a bigger house?

Comment: Note that *for* and *against* are prepositions, not nouns like *pro* and *con*.

Comment: in any case, you could not construct it as "We discussed **for and against of buying**...". You would need to say "We discussed **the {reasons/arguments} for and against buying**..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, no!

[*pros* and *cons*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pros-and-cons) typically talk about *advantages* and *disadvantages* of something. And it, I think, is the most acceptable phrase. Replacing it with 'for' and 'against' would make that sentence a bit ambiguous. In other words, you may need to *clarify* to a few (including me!) who may not get it at first.

---

Some believe that [*for* and *against* works in *debates*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130613105351AA8MlzB)

Comment: So, it's not common in informal speach. isn't?

Comment: I've not heard yet! :)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock would you mind moving this comment under the question? Because it's OP who constructed it.

Comment: @MaulikV I think Brian Hitchcock's was pointing out that your answer is misleading: "discussed for and against of " is not ambiguous, it's ungrammatical.

Comment: My bad. Moving it.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I've read 'for and against' in the same order. It's grammatical. **But** in this context, it'll look ambiguous or making the sentence weird. That's what I said. Anyway, Brian got it and moved it! :)

Comment: *For and against* is grammatical, but *\*discussion for and against of* is ungrammatical.

Comment: http://www.abc.net.au/newsradio/content/s4284865.htm @snailboat

Comment: There's no *of* there, so it doesn't contradict what I wrote.

Comment: I wasn't sure about whether it's grammatical before reading comments here. But it did sound ambiguous and so I wrote. Maybe, ungrammatical is weird, and weird looks ambiguous to me! @snailboat

Comment: @MaulikV Is this ambiguous to you? "We discussed the reasons/arguments for and against buying a bigger house."

Comment: That looks okay! @DamkerngT. No ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

*pros and cons* is usually used to describe how desirable the attributes of the Object or effects of an action ( buying a big house) are, usually projected in future.

> Pros: Big house will allow kids to have separate rooms etc.
>
> Cons: The air-conditioning bill will be higher, etc.

*for and against* is usually used for counting support by people or institutions.

> The Husband was for buying a big house
>
> The Wife was against buying the big house.

If you said "We discussed all the points *for and against* buying a big house", that is accepted usage. So I am coming around to thinking, if you can count things to tally, it's for-against, if not, it's  pros/cons.